# Regex o Similar para eliminar texto después de texto

Tags: regex, asp.net-core

Me gustaría poder eliminar un texto que tengo en un String y que varía constantemente.
Tengo este texto:

`{{    "fechaModificacion": "2019-04-17T15:31:38.000Z",    "nombreDocumento": "Basico - papel 27 04 17.pdf",    "tipoDocumental": "25",    "fechaCreacion": "2019-04-17T15:31:38.000Z",    "Borrado": true,    "Identificador": "161151-1",    "Contador": 1,    "Contador2": 0,    "usuarioModificacion": "ICMADMIN",    "tipoMime": "application/pdf",    "tamano": "70238",    "usuarioCreacion": "ICMADMIN",    "bytes": "JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjQgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgNzAyMzgvTyA2L0UgNjYzNzYvTiAxLEM0Qjc3NTREREQwRTEwNDFCQjFERjE5QTg0QjJDNjMzPl0+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQoxMTYNCiUlRU9GDQo=", "propiedadX" : "1", "propiedadY" : "2"}}`

Y me gustaría poder eliminar, siempre, el apartado siguiente:

`"bytes": "JVBERi0xLjQNJeLjz9MNCjQgMCBvYmoNPDwvTGluZWFyaXplZCAxL0wgNzAyMzgvTyA2L0UgNjYzNzYvTiAxLEM0Qjc3NTREREQwRTEwNDFCQjFERjE5QTg0QjJDNjMzPl0+Pg0Kc3RhcnR4cmVmDQoxMTYNCiUlRU9GDQo="`

El texto después de la palabra "bytes" es diferente siempre.
Estaba pensando en hacerlo con un Regex, pero no sé si hay alguna otra manera mejor.

Un saludo,

---

El resultado final que busco es:

`{{    "fechaModificacion": "2019-04-17T15:31:38.000Z",    "nombreDocumento": "Basico - papel 27 04 17.pdf",    "tipoDocumental": "25",    "fechaCreacion": "2019-04-17T15:31:38.000Z",    "Borrado": true,    "Identificador": "161151-1",    "Contador": 1,    "Contador2": 0,    "usuarioModificacion": "ICMADMIN",    "tipoMime": "application/pdf",    "tamano": "70238",    "usuarioCreacion": "ICMADMIN", "propiedadX" : "1", "propiedadY" : "2"}}`

Todo el texto antes y después del "bytes".

Answer (score 0):

Hice un ejemplo de expresión regular para ese texto especificamente.

```
/"bytes": ".*?",/
```

Explicación:

- `"bytes": "` -> busca este texto especificamente.
- `.*` -> A partir de aquí permite cualquier texto.
- `?",` -> Hasta llegar a la primero coincidencia de los caracteres `",`.

Resumen: Cualquier texto que haya entre los caracteres `"bytes": "` a los caracteres `",`.

Comment: Puedes quitar los paréntesis en la expresión regular. En este caso no aportan nada.